# OpenVPN restriction

Tags: openvpn, restriction

Ive set up an OpenVPN server at my place and handed out a certificate to a client who has an openvpn client at his place.

I need require that he should be able to connect to the vpn server only from one IP address (his current one).  How can I do this?

Comment: what's the OS - is openvpn running under linux/windows/sth else?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe OpenVPN has any built-in method to control access based on IP address.  You probably will need to use either your border firewall, or the firewall for that host OS to limit access as required.

Personally, I am not sure that it is worth the effort.  If you have a good set of keys and HMAC authentication there is very low chance of anyone else being able to get it.

Comment: sounds like the client may be using the host as a bridge point for their private net, in which case if the vpnclient is moved to another location, the cert will still be valid, but the host may not be in the appropriate and safe network.